# Magento: how to call static block in category page within content

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to call a static cms block with id BLOCKID from within the content section of the category. I tried using the following and it doesn't work:

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="BLOCKID"}}
```

I am able to call it using Custom Layout Update using the following code but it doesn't allow me control over the location where within content it will appear.

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="cms/block" name="BLOCKID">
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>BLOCKID</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>'
```

There is a specific section in my text located in the content section where I want this block to appear.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can call a static block within a static block.  You can copy all of your category content into a new static block, referencing the other static block for that specific section.  Then back in your category, remove all of the content, go to Display, set Display Mode -> Static Block Only, and choose the new static block you just made.

Comment: Thank you that worked. If you post it as an answer then you can get credit for it.

Comment: Cool.  I wish there was a similar workaround for adding blocks to products.  That's a real pain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick a static block into category content, there is an easy workaround.  To keep things straight for this example, let's say the category is "Cameras" and your static block is "camera-deals".

- Go to your category, copy all of the content.
- Create a new static block named "cameras-content" or something similar
- Paste your category content into this new static block, insert your existing "camera-deals" static block where you want it to go. Save
- Return to the category, delete the content that you previously copied
- In the Display tab, set Display Mode -> Static Block (can be either just the static block or with products, both work)
- Choose the "cameras-content" for your static block (this block can have variables and static blocks inside of it.) Save

Basically, it's easy to call files in the media folder, variables, blocks, and widgets from a static block...but out of the box you can't do that in category content. So just don't do that, haha.  Have your category refer to a static block and then do all of your fancy things in that block.